# python cdk to create lambda trigger on s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

Hi I want to create a trigger on lambda function when a new json file is uploaded on s3 bucket. rule for trigger are

Trigger Rules for Lambda invocation using s3

```
**folder name** on which it will trigger is : input-files 
**file name**  ending with _processed.json OR 000.json
```

I am trying this but not working and not sure about multiple rules for file ending

```
trigger-_lambda.add_event_source(_aws_lambda_event_sources.S3EventSource(
            bucket,
              events=[
                  _s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
              filters=[
                  _s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                      prefix="input",
                      suffix="_processed.json" , "000.json ")]
            ))
```

is this the way to do this properly ? any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 doesn't allow you to define multiple suffix rules in a filter.

To work around this, you would need to define two separate event sources:

```
my_lambda.add_event_source(
    lambda_event_sources.S3EventSource(
        bucket,
        events=[s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
        filters=[
            s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                prefix="input",
                suffix="_processed.json",
            ),

        ],
    )
)
my_lambda.add_event_source(
    lambda_event_sources.S3EventSource(
        bucket,
        events=[s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
        filters=[
            s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                prefix="input",
                suffix="000.json",
            ),
        ],
    )
)
```

Comment: hi thanks for answer ! 1 little confusion  prefix="input" means folder name started with input or file name started with input ?

Comment: as my folder name is input-files

Comment: There are no "folders" in S3 - just objects with keys. The web console splits the object keys by the `/` symbol to create the illusion of folders. So the prefix/suffix would apply to the entire object key - including the virtual "folder names".

Comment: sir getting this error  `Cannot specify more than one suffix rule in a filter.` when I tried this .  that's why reopening

Comment: You're right, my bad. Updated the answer.